# JSDoc to document the type of the `this` variable

Tags: jsdoc

Given a function like the following, how can I document what the type of `this` is?

```
function onClone() {
  if(this.department != this.creator.department) {
    reviews.append(new PendingReview(this.department));
  }
}
```

I would expect to use `/** @this {Submission} */`, but [the JSDoc docs specify that `@this` is to be followed by a `namePath`](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-this.html). Since the provided code is separate from any other code that could be used to explain what `this` is, I want to provide hints about what type of object you're looking at.

In other words, the following is invalid:

```
/** @this {Submission} */
function onClone() {
  if(this.department != this.creator.department) {
    reviews.append(new PendingReview(this.department));
  }
}
```

Comment: You say the example is invalid -- where is it failing?  Closure Compiler, JSDoc generation, Salsa / VS Code...?  The way I read the [namepath docs](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html) it sounds like `Submission` is a perfectly valid namepath referring to a class.

Comment: JSDoc generation results in a global symbol called `onClone`, instead of `Submission#onClone`. Not even their [provided example](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-this.html#examples) works.